# loop hangs for iterated std::erase on std::list

Tags: c++, hash, stl, iterator

I'm trying to remove duplicate combinations of integer vectors stored in a list using a hash table. Iterating over each integer vector in the list, I:

1. Calculate the hash_value (thash)
2. See if the hash value is already in the hash table (pids)
3. If it's in the hash table, erase that vector from the list.
   Otherwise, add that value to the hash_table and increment the list
   iterator

Print statements seem to confirm my logic, but the loop hangs at the fourth step of iteration. I've commented the `it++` and `vz.remove(it)` that cause the problem and only show the logic in the code below. The code is also available through ideone: https://ideone.com/JLGA0f

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<list>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<unordered_set>
    using namespace std;

    double hash_cz(std::vector<int> &cz, std::vector<double> &lprimes) {
      double pid = 0;
      for(auto it = cz.begin(); it != cz.end(); it++) {
        pid += lprimes[*it];
      }
      return pid;
    }

    int main(){
      // create list of vectors
      std::list<std::vector<int>> vz;
      vz.push_back({2,1});
      vz.push_back({1,2});
      vz.push_back({1,3});
      vz.push_back({1,2,3});
      vz.push_back({2, 1});

      // vector of log of prime numbers
      std::vector<double> lprimes {2, 3, 5, 7};
      for (auto it = lprimes.begin(); it != lprimes.end(); it++) {
        *it = std::log(*it);
      }

      std::unordered_set<double> pids;
      double thash;
      for (auto it = vz.begin(); it != vz.end(); ) {
        thash = hash_cz(*it, lprimes);
        std::cout << thash << std::endl;
        // delete element if its already been seen
        if (pids.find(thash) != pids.end()) {
           std::cout << "already present. should remove from list" << std::endl;
           // vz.erase(it);
        }
        else {
          // otherwise add it to hash_table and increment pointer
          std::cout << "not present. add to hash. keep in list." << std::endl;
          pids.insert(thash);
          // it++;
        }
        it++;
      }

      for (auto it = vz.begin(); it != vz.end(); it++) {
        for (auto j = it -> begin(); j != it -> end(); j++) {
          std::cout << *j << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this line of code:

```
vz.erase(it);
```

It keeps iterator where it was ie leaves it invalid. It should be either:

```
vz.erase(it++);
```

or

```
it = vz.erase( it );
```

Note: `std::unoredered_set::insert()` return value tells you if insert was succesfull or not (if the same value element is there already), you should call it and check result. In your code you do lookup twice:

```
if (pids.insert(thash).second ) { 
    // new element added
    ++it;
} else { 
    // insertion failed, remove 
    it = vz.erase( it );
}
```

As `std::list` provides [`remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) your code can be simplified:

```
vz.remove_if( [&pids,&lprimes]( auto &v ) { 
   return !pids.insert( hash_cz(v, lprimes) ).second );
} );
```

instead of whole loop.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you so much for your help. And thanks for the tip about inserting into ```unordered_sets```.

Answer (score 1):

If the element has already been seen, you erase() the `it` node and then increment `it` at the end of the loop: undefined behaviour. Try erase(it++) instead.

If the element has not been seen, you increment `it` and then do it again at the end of `for`, yielding UB if `it` was `end() - 1` as it moves past end.

Comment: So simple. Thanks for the clarification!